# Trying to Insert data using JDBC Outbound Gateway ,But the data is not being inserted into the tables & could not see the errors in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

```
    <bean id="eventMapper" class="ca.customer.model.eventDAO.EventServiceMapper"/>
    <int-jdbc:outbound-gateway data-source="dataSource"
                                    request-channel="jdbcRequestChannel"
                                    reply-channel="jdbcResponseChannel"
                                    update="Insert into INTEGRATION_LOGS (EVENT_SEQ_ID, REQUEST,CREATEDBY,CREATE_TIMESTAMP) 
                                    values(:eventSeqId,:request,:createdBy,:createTimestamp)"
                                    query="select * from EVENT_INTEGRATION_LOGS where EVENT_SEQ_ID = :eventSeqId"
                                    request-sql-parameter-source-factory="requestSource"
                                    reply-sql-parameter-source-factory="replySource"
                                    row-mapper="eventMapper"
                                    keys-generated="true"/>
    
        <bean id="requestSource" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
            <property name="parameterExpressions">
                <map>
                    <entry key="eventSeqId" value="59824"/>
                    <entry key="request" value="tests values ----"/>
                    <entry key="createdBy" value="BMF"/>
                    <entry key="createTimestamp" value="new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())"/>                    
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    
                                    
        <bean id="replySource" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
            <property name="parameterExpressions">
                <map>
                    <entry key="eventSeqId" value="59824"/>
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean> 
        
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>
    
    `Below is Data Source Configurations`
    
        <bean  id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
            <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@cad-222.dev.bce.ca:2222:DV2DB" />
            <property name="password" value="password123" />
            <property name="user" value="root" />
            <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
                <props merge="default">
                    <prop key="MinLimit">3</prop>
                    <prop key="MaxLimit">20</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

by using JDBC Outbound Gateway for inserting the data into database tables ,But the data is not being inserted into the tables & could not see any errors logs in spring integration.
we need help is there anything missed .

Comment: Well, you definitely must see some errors in logs: your expressions are wrong, they just not fit into SpEL syntax. That `"59824"` would lead to something like `no property in Message object`. That `Timestamp` is not in a `java.lang` package, so it would fail not finding such a class for instantiating. And so on. It would be great to know how you send a message to that `jdbcRequestChannel`, so that would be a place when you need to handle exceptions thrown from this `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>`.